# Include Css Intellisense from one project in another

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, cdn

I have multiple web apps running on a server that all use a lot of the same css/image files. In order make everything more centralized i've taken all of the files out of the projects and wrote a small static file server in asp.net core with some gulp tasks to manage the css. The goal was to have it act like a cdn (with only one machine) and serve some other api functions, but to work locally without internet access.

I figured that if i included the visual studio project in the solutions for my other projects they would have access to the css/scss files for intellisense, which was not the case.

Is there some way that i can reference the files in visual studio so that i can get auto completion in the apps' view files?

Comment: enable the catch and dont delete them. It will automatically take the cached versions of css, unless you make any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a symbolic link that included the assets in the desired project.